# xml conditional XElement creation

Tags: c#, xml

I build this xml file:

```
   var persons = new[] {
   new Person {
      Name = "Patrick Hines",
      PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0144", "425-555-0145" }
   },
   new Person {
      Name = "Gretchen Rivas",
      PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0163" }
   }
};
            XElement contacts =
               new XElement("contacts",
                  from p in persons
                  where p.Name.StartsWith("G")
                  select new XElement("contact",
                     new XElement("name", p.Name),
                     from ph in p.PhoneNumbers
                     select new XElement("phone", ph)
                  )
               );


        class Person
        {
            public string Name;
            public string[] PhoneNumbers;
        }
```

In this sample the phonenumber is not null. How do I code it that it wont create a  element in my xml when the phone number string  is empty or null?

Comment: Add `where` expression. eg. `from ph in p.PhoneNumbers where ph!=null
select new XElement("phone", ph)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out null and empty strings from PhoneNumbers:

```
   from ph in p.PhoneNumbers where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ph)
```